# Is it a mandatory condition that complex poles and zeros should always exist as conjugate pairs?

Tags: poles-zeros, control-systems

Complex poles and zeros always exist in conjugate pairs?If not always, in which context applicable?

https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=32090&seqNum=9

The above link mentions related idea with eq 3.50

The above link is related to control systems and since control systems and signal processing are some how linked, please try to answer/comment for general case and also specifically for these two subjects (control systems and signal processing)in context

Comment: No, they don't have to for complex systems. Context is key, as always.

Comment: Try doing a search on "roots of polynomials with real valued coefficients".

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra will show that this is true. The result applies generally, so don't get caught up in the specifics of signal processing.

Comment: @Envidia Do you mean"generally Complex poles and zeros always exist in conjugate pair except some scenarios in signal processing"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any polynomial with real coefficients, the roots if complex will always be in complex pairs, since if we do have a complex root the product of the factored polynomial can only have real coefficient if multiplied with it's complex conjugate.

To see this simply, consider that angles add in the product of a complex number. A generalized complex number with real magnitude $K$ and real angle $\theta$ can be written in exponential form as $Ke^{j\theta}$. The complex conjugate of this is $Ke^{-j\theta}$ and the product would always be real:

$$Ke^{j\theta}Ke^{-j\theta} = K^2e^{j0} = K^2$$

Similarly the addition of two complex conjugate values would be real which is clear when the complex number is written in real plus imaginary form with $I$ is the real number and $jQ$ is the imaginary number, as:

$$Ke^{j\theta} = I + jQ$$
$$Ke^{-j\theta} = I - jQ$$

$$Ke^{j\theta} + Ke^{-j\theta} = (I + jQ) + (I - jQ) = 2I$$

For poles and zeros, as the roots of associated polynomials which can be factored into a product of first order forms:

$$P_z(s) = (s-z_1)(s-z_2)(s-z_2)\ldots$$

Where $z_n$ represents the zeros, and similarly for the poles

$$P_p(s) = (s-p_1)(s-p_2)(s-p_2)\ldots$$

Where $p_n$ represents the poles;

For every complex zero or pole that exists, in order for the entire product to be real, a complex conjugate pair must also exist as demonstrated by the following product:

$$(s-p_1)(s-p^*_1) = s^2 - p_1 s - p^*_1 s + p_1 p^*_1 = s^2 + s(p_1 +p^*_1) +p_1 p^*_1$$

Where we see the complex conjugate sum and product occur that would result in real coefficients.

Similarly, for any polynomial with complex coefficients, the poles and zeros will not be in complex conjugate pairs.

One example from radio communications where complex poles will not exist in complex pairs is a baseband IIR filter to correct for spectral asymmetry: this can occur when a modulated signal passes through a channel where the signal content above the carrier frequency has higher loss than the signal content below the carrier frequency. In a direct conversion receiver, this waveform is frequency translated directly to baseband and would be represented as a complex signal. Any filter with real coefficients would have the same magnitude response (and conjugate phase response) for the upper (positive frequencies) and lower (negative frequencies) sidebands. We require a filter with complex coefficients in order to filter the positive and negative frequencies differently.

Comment: So in nutshell you mean"For any polynomial with real coefficients, the roots if complex will always be in complex pairs and for any polynomial with complex coefficients, the poles and zeros will not be in complex conjugate pairs"??

Comment: @engr Yes exactly. This is not very different from the property that the spectrum for any real waveform will be complex conjugate symmetric when you consider how poles and zeros represent frequency locations on the s-plane. If you're not readily familiar with all that then the details of complex conjugate products and sums given in this answer should be sufficient explanation.